# Elemento HTML não se torna visível

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tenho o seguinte HTML:

```
<form action="cadastro/cadastrando.php" method="post">
    <div class="elemf">
        <label>Nome</label>
        <input id="nome" type="text" name="nome" maxlength="15"/>
        <p class="nome_erro">Campo Obrigatório. São permitidos letras e acentos.</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Quando eu tirar o foco do campo de texto e ele estiver vazio, deve aparecer a mensagem que está com a classe `'nome_erro'`. No entanto ela não aparece, parece que o código executa o método abaixo, mas não muda o valor do atributo `display`, continuando `'none'`.

Segue o CSS:

```
.erro {
    font: 12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #ff0000;
    left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.nome_erro {
    display: none;
}
```

E o Javascript:

```
$(document).on('blur','input, textarea, select', function() {
    if($(this).val() === '') {
        switch($(this).attr('id')) {
            case 'nome':
                $('.nome_erro').addClass('erro');
                break;
        }
    } else {
        switch($(this).attr('id')) {
            case 'nome':
                $('#nome_erro').removeClass('erro');
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você têm um conflito de prioridades. Use assim:

```
display: inline-block !important;
```

O `!important` força o display a ser `inline-block`, sobrepondo-se a `none`

**Exemplo online: http://jsfiddle.net/uY2eq/**

---

**Nota:** Como o LeoFelipe apontou e bem, mudei também no segundo `switch` o indicador de ID `#` para classe `.`, ou seja de

```
$('#nome_erro').removeClass('erro');
```

para

```
$('.nome_erro').removeClass('erro');
```

Comment: Ainda está faltando a alteração que @LeoFelipe comentou na resposta dele. Trocar o seletor de `#` para `.` no else .

Comment: Realmente, estava ocorrendo o conflito, mas o estranho é que em outro locais do projeto que estou fazendo, não estava com este problema, de certa forma estranho

Comment: essa parte do # e . , foi que esqueci de desfazer as alterações, antes de postar a pergunta

Comment: Lembrando que a declaração `!important` é desencorajada, já que pode gerar efeitos indesejados e erros de estilo "complexos" em projetos com muitas linhas / arquivos CSS.

Answer (score 4):

As respostas do Sergio e do LeoFelipe estão corretas. De minha parte vou propor uma forma diferente de fazer a mesma coisa, com menos código:

```
var nome_erro = $(".nome_erro");
$("#nome").blur(function () {
    nome_erro.toggle(!this.value);
});
```

A primeira linha transforma o elemento numa variável, assim você não executa uma `query` a cada execução do blur. Isso melhora a performance.

Comment: Pode usar somente: `!this.value`. Boa optimização `+1`

Comment: @Sergio tem razão. Gosto de código curto e simples, vou mudar para essa forma.

Answer (score 3):

1º) Seu remove Class tá setando #nome_erro e deveria ser .nome_erro.

2º) Eu costumo usar .show() e .hide(). Exemplo:

```
$('.nome_erro').hide();

if($(this).val() === ''){
    switch($(this).attr('id')){
        case 'nome':
            $('.nome_erro').show(); break;
    }
}
else{
    switch($(this).attr('id')){
        case 'nome':
            $('.nome_erro').hide(); break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Notei que em seu código você está validando todos os campos `input,select ...`, há um problema nisto, se houveram campos não obrigatórios, isto te trará problemas, se você pretende criar seu próprio validate, vou deixar uma dica, **apenas didática**, que você pode tomar como base e implementá-lo.

Form

```
<form name="form" id="form">
   <label for="nome">Nome <small>(obrigatório)</small></label>
   <input type="text" name="nome" data-required="true" />
   <small class="erro">Nome obrigatório</small>
   <label for="end">Endereço <small>(Não obrigatório)</small></label>
   <input type="text" name="end"/>
   <label for="end">Mensagem <small>(Obrigatório)</small></label>
   <textarea name="msg" data-required="true"></textarea>
   <small class="erro">Mensagem obrigatória</small>
   <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

CSS

```
label,input,textarea,button{display: block;}
small.erro {display:none; color:red;}
```

Jquery

```
$.validate = {
    classErro: '.erro', //classe padrão de exibição de erros
    start: function(form){ // função para inicializar a validação
        //testa todos os campos que tiverem o atributo data-required
        $(form+' *[data-required]').on('blur',function(){
            if ($(this).val() == ''){ // se o campo estiver vazio, mostra erro
                $(this).next($.validate.classErro).show();
            } else { 
                $(this).next($.validate.classErro).hide(); 
            }
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
           //testa o form no momento do submit
           $(form).submit(function(event){
               if(!$.validate.validSubmit(form)){
                   //se não passar na validação impede o submit
                   event.preventDefault();
               }
           });
        });
      },
      //função para validar no momento do submit
      validSubmit: function(form){
         // procura por campos com attr required
         $(form+' *[data-required]').each(function(){ 
             if ($(this).val() == ''){
                 $(this).next($.validate.classErro).show();
             } else { 
                 $(this).next($.validate.classErro).hide(); 
             }
         });
         // se houver erro retorna falso
         if($(form+' small.erro:visible').length > 0){ 
             return false;
         }
         return true;
       }
  };

// inicia a função passando como parametro o id do form
$.validate.start('#form');
```

**Exemplo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vNMs/)**

Tomando como base este exemplo, você poderá criar outras funções para validar por exemplo:

- Datas
- Email
- Telefone
- CPF e CPNJ

Entre outros, boa sorte!

Answer (score 1):

O CSS respeita a lei da sobrescrição, ou seja, o que vem por último é que tem prioridade. Sendo assim, a solução seria inverter a ordem das classes:

```
.nome_erro {
    display: none;
}
.nome_erro.erro {
    font: 12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #ff0000;
    left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Exemplo: **[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/b4yxP/)**